# How can I call segue from uitableviewcell class? Not controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue

Not controller. I want to call segue from the customcell.swift class

Also preparefor segue method does not show

Comment: Surely you can find your answer in [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+segue+uitableviewcell).

Answer (score 2):

It happens because you’re not into in the view controller more, and you don’t have access to navigation stack methods...

A great way to solve this, you can just use delegate pattern using protocol.

So you can create a protocol with an action as the code below:

```
protocol CustomCellDelegate {
   func didTapAnyButton(_ anyParam: String)
}
```

Into your UITableViewCell, you just create this delegate property:

`weak var delegate: CustomCellDelegate?`

Ps: I’ve created with weak to avoid memory leaks, and the optional, because the property will initialized with nil value, and the viewController will set the value to this property after it was already created.

So, in your ViewController you can just implement this protocol:

```
extension ViewController: CustomCellDelegate {
   func didTapAnyButton(_ anyParam: String) {
       performSegue()
   }
}
```

At least you should just assign the ViewController delegate when you instantiate the CustomCell, considering you have an UITableViewCell called CustomCell:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier(“CustomCel”) as! CustomCell

cell.delegate = self
```

After that, you can just call the delegate method tapAnyButton at the action you need to implement, for example:

`delegate.didTapAnyButton(“Some Param that I need to pass on segue method.”)`

So when you call this method, the ViewController that assigned this delegate protocol will be trigged! And in the ViewController you have access to the segue method.